# Opening and reading content of the file with custom extention

Tags: android

I want to open up a file in my application with a custom extension say .ccf
And read the content of the file. it's a simple text file nothing else but i am changing the extension because i want only my app to read it.
i am using following `intent-filter` to open that file. but i don't know how to read the contents.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"    android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccf" />
        <data android:scheme="https"   android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccf" />
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccf" />
         <data android:scheme="file"   android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ccf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Just like .PDF file open in Adobe reader.
Need help.

Comment: Why not just read this file and show content in EditText or TextView?

Comment: I want use to click on it and then open it in my app. just like .pdf opens in adobe reader.

Comment: Opening and reading a file has nothing to do with the intent filters, it is normal java file reading,  if you are referring to how to obtain the file name in your application, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i want user to click on the file and open the file in my application . is it clear now ???

Comment: Were you able to get the file name in your application? What have you tried to do so far? Are you using a guide/tutorial? If so which one?

Comment: Android works with MIME types better than file extensions for this sort of thing.